# Wildfly/Hibernate query result fails to return persisted entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, wildfly

With Wildfly 16, using the EntityManager I persist a new entity and invoke another routine to perform an HQL query to retrieve that entity, but it fails to return.

This is running server side and is normally triggered by a client command. The command should cause the new object to be persisted, then call a routine used in several places that selects objects (like and including the newly persisted one) and format and push them to subscribers.

I've tried a few things to get this working:

- Flush the EntityManager prior to the HQL query
- Reuse the EntityManager via the invoked routine (with and without flushing post persist())

The only way I've managed to get the desired results is to cause the initial client command to persist the entity, then perform a second client command to retrieve the entity persisted via the first command. This is not an issue with the HQL retrieving the data as it does work - it just doesn't work immediately after persisting the entity. It seems like either the data isn't persisted prior to the HQL query or the HQL query is looking at something cached (although I haven't specifically set anything like that, so it would have to be a default I'm unaware of).

An example of the three routines:

```
//Routine A - calls B & C
routineB();
routineC();

//Routine B
EntityManager em = emProvider.getEntityManager(); //pulls em from a stateless bean tagged @PersistenceContext
Blah blah = new Blah();
em.persist(blah);
em.flush();

//Routine C
EntityManager em = emProvider.getEntityManager();
List<Blah> blahs = em.createNamedQuery("retrieveBlah").getResultList();
//do some stuff with blahs... except it's missing blah from Routine A
```

My persistence.xml settings JIC that's relevant

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
```

I need to be able to persist and retrieve the persisted via HQL query as the result of a single client command.

Comment: You have to check how is configured transaction isolation in your application env. If emProvider.getEntityManager() create a new EM in a new transaction you can't query the new entity until the transaction opened by routing A is committed. Try to create the EM outside routines and pass to them as parameter

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the post above was missing the key bit of information to resolve the issue. After posting this I continued testing and discovered the piece I overlooked, "routineB()" was marked @Asynchronous. So it was executing in parallel to routineC().

Comment: thanks for returning to post the answer to your own question